# Can't add connections to IIS 7 in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration, connection

I enabled IIS but I can't add connections to IIS 7 in windows 7 ultimate. Under File it just has "save connections" which is disabled/'greyed out' and exit.

Following picture is just to clarify:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature is not available in Client SKUs out-of-the-box, however you can install Remote Administration for IIS Manager which will add that functionality to it. It is available at: http://www.iis.net/download/IISManager

After that you will have the ability to open connections, etc.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thx

Comment: You'll also need to enable this feature on the server: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2015/11/02/configure-an-iis-server-core-server-for-remote-management/